# O chat pode ser usado para tirar dúvidas não relacionadas às perguntas do SO?

Tags: debate, chat

Olá, pessoal!

Ás vezes, sinto vontade de trocar uma ideia sobre alguns assuntos que, muitas vezes, não se encaixariam tão bem em perguntar no Stack Overflow, por diferentes motivos:

- A pergunta pode ser rapidamente direcionada a outras, conforme as respostas
- Você tem uma ideia muito crua da dúvida inicial, e as respostas podem guiar melhor você para especificar a dúvida

Normalmente, são perguntas sem código para mostrar, mais voltado a boas práticas, opiniões (o que não se encaixa tão bem no SO), arquitetura, etc. Sei que poderia fazer tudo isto pelo próprio SO ou nas outras comunidades (em inglês), abrindo mais de uma pergunta conforme as coisas caminharem. Contudo, pensei se o chat poderia ser usado para isto, como se fosse uma troca de ideias na hora do cafézinho :).

Confesso que não acompanho o chat, mas das vezes que entrei lá vi um clima legal de descontração e o pessoal falando de programação, mas normalmente com atenção voltada ao que está ocorrendo no SO.

Abraços!

Comment: O chat é na verdade para tratarmos, prioritariamente, sobre assuntos do site. Mas a gente costuma entrar num clima de zoeira, de vez enquanto (claro, tudo com muito respeito).

Comment: @WallaceMaxters _"de vez enquanto"_ haha :)

Comment: @Sergio durante o "feriado de fim de ano" praticamente não teve. Adivinha o que tinha de diferente? :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O ideal é fazer perguntas no site porque isso fica registrado para todos poderem aproveitar o conhecimento que você ajudou gerar, mesmo que só perguntando.

Particularmente não gosto quando a pessoa transfere o que pode estar no site para o chat, mesmo que seja o dúvida boba.

O que é diferente do caso onde não caberia no site. Se não está no escopo, se não consegue fazer a pergunta com clareza, se depende de opinião, aí provavelmente é caso para o chat mesmo. Ele é feito para isto. Em tese ele deveria ser usado só para falar do site e de assuntos de programação que não cabem no site. Sua percepção está correta.

Se a dúvida é muito ampla pode complicar um pouco. Se é difícil responder algo muito amplo no site, no chat pode ser pior ainda. Claro que existem amplas por outro motivos, se é ampla por que são muitos assuntos, basta desmembrar em várias perguntas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. De fato, seria melhor fazer as perguntas e gerar este conteúdo. Às vezes elas são muito abrangentes. Exemplo: "_Vi diferentes maneiras de mapear entidades de domínio no DDD e como salvá-las, mas todos exemplos que encontrei são muito crus, não respondem minhas dúvidas. Também nunca achei códigos de exemplo que abranjam uma aplicação grande, com complicações extras, como tabelas legadas. Existe um bom exemplo?_". Eu poderia especificar todas estas dúvidas e seria bem interessante, mas demoraria dias para alcançar meu objetivo de entender o DDD.